# How to create drop-down list in SSRS based on WHERE clause below?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, dataset

At my organization we using UI third party tool that communicates with SQL database. I have access to a database, but not to the tool.

Based on a stored procedure below user able to choose from drop-down list `DairyStatus` `"Open"`, `"Closed"`, or `"Both"`

[image]

```
ALTER Procedure
AS
@ShowOpen bit = 0,
@ShowClosed bit = 0
 SELECT
 FROM 
 WHERE 
              AND
                        (
                        (CASE WHEN (@ShowOpen = 1) THEN
                              CASE WHEN (tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL and tblNoteRecipients.IsDiary = 1) or tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

                        ELSE
                              1
                        END = 1)
                  AND
                        (CASE WHEN (@ShowClosed = 1) THEN
                              CASE WHEN (tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                        ELSE
                              1
                        END = 1)
                  OR    ((@ShowOpen = 1) AND (@ShowClosed = 1))
                        )
```

So my question is how can I make same drop-down list in SSRS?
What would be the data-set in order to populate this drop-down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a parameter in ssrs with 3 static values(open closed both)
in where clause it should be something like :

```
( @DairyStatus = 'open' and ((tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS NULL and tblNoteRecipients.IsDiary = 1) or tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID is null)) or
( @DairyStatus = 'closed' and tblNoteRecipients.CompletedDate IS not NULL) or
  @DairyStatus = 'both'
```